# Assistance Needed with Python RegX, Lists

Tags: python, list

Trying to split a string from a pdf using python. I was able to extract the data from the PDF however cannot make a vertical list.

Original Data from PDF Looks like this:
'First Name1', 'Last Name1', 'First Name2', 'Last Name2','First Name3', 'Last Name3',etc

But I want the list to look like this

'First Name1', 'Last Name1',
'First Name2', 'Last Name2',
'First Name3', 'Last Name3',

Comment: What do you mean by a vertical list?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original data looks like this:

```
data = ['First Name1', 'Last Name1', 'First Name2', 'Last Name2','First Name3', 'Last Name3']
```

You can just retrieve every other item:

```
x = [[data[i], data[i + 1]] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]
```

And the result will be a nested list that you can retrieve data from:

```
x -> [['First Name1', 'Last Name1'], ['First Name2', 'Last Name2'], ['First Name3', 'Last Name3']]

x[0] -> ['First Name1', 'Last Name1']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to understand what exactly it is you're trying to achieve. There is no such thing as a 'vertical list' in Python.

Do you want to group every `First NameX` with `Last NameX`? In that case, you could make [`tuples`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) out of the pairs.

Do you want to print your list to the console while grouping every `First NameX` with `Last NameX`? In that case, it's still easier to make tuples out of them, and print them like this:

```py
my_list = [('First Name1', 'Last Name1'), ('First Name2', 'Last Name2'), ('First Name3', 'Last Name3')]

for elem in my_list:
    print(elem[0], elem[1])
```